# Wordpress regionalization content

Tags: php, wordpress

im working on a plugin that will show different content in different regions of the world (no multi site wanted):

es. US, UK, IT, FR...

I've start from creating a taxonomy and terms, one for each region (US, UK...). 
Then i used the pre_get_post filter to do a new query based on the term that the user as select in the home. 
I did this usin a form in the home, and assigning the value of the term to a session, so that the pre_get_post filter have the same term during the all user navigation.

i'm stuck, because i would like that if the user select the term "US", the url should be mysite.com/US or mysite.com/US/%postname% for all the session...
any ideas? or maybe i've got it wrong from the beginning ...and so any suggestion is accepted.
Thanx

Comment: If you have it in a session, why do you want it in the url?  Those would be "competing" (or duplicate) variables.  Choose either the URL (hard to do in WordPress) or the session (better to use cookies in WordPress, FYI).

Comment: Thanx for your reply, is very hard in wordpress with the url...session is easy as you say...but what i really need is that when the user select a region, the url takes that region like this /en so that the url identify what region content we are in...

Comment: Then what you are going to need to do is add an [url rewrite endpoint](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/) in your plugin so that you can do something like: `www.mysite.com/page-slug/lang/`en (where `/lang` is the endpoint, and `en` is an example variable)

Comment: Thanks again a very good guide! end point is not a solution in my case, because i'll need something like the wpml urls...where the country is just at the base of the url. www.mydomain.com/EN/post-name, the end point goes at the end of the url.